# Restrictive read permissions and file get contents

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, phpseclib

I am using PHPSecLib with this code:

```
ssh = new Net_SSH2('my-ec2-dns');
$key = new Crypt_RSA();
$key->loadKey(file_get_contents('my-ec2-private-key'));
```

Only I have access to computer and server.

I get a permission denied on file_get_contents since ec2 instances require 400 permissions on the private key.

How can I get around this issue so I can SSH into my server within a PHP env?

Comment: What if instead of doing `$rsa->loadKey(file_get_contents(...))` you just copy / paste the key and do `$rsa->loadKey(...)`?

Comment: That's what I did. Thanks for chiming in though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to achieve this, is to circumvent security measures in some way or another.

Possible solution:

- Copy you private key to another file with more lenient permissions
  (640).
- Add the user under which the web server is running in your group so it can access the file
- Make sure the web server is not chroot-ed in any way so it can reach your file or add a symlink (needs +FollowSymlink)

Comment: I copied the contents of the key to another file like you suggested with 640 and did file_get_contents on that. Thanks for a nudge in right direction.